# Detect string on CSV data array and add 2 cells before

Tags: python, pandas

I'm so confused with a csv data treatment, any help will be nice.

I've a csv file with multiple columns like this:

```
col_1;col_2;col_3;col_4;col_5;col_6;col_7;col_8;
Object1;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;someword;789
Object2;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;someword;789
Object3;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;someword;789
Object4;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;someword;789
```

But some Objects have a missing data on col_6, col_7 and col_8, instead of it there's a Keyword in col_6 like this:

```
col_1;col_2;col_3;col_4;col_5;col_6;col_7;col_8;
Object1;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;someword;789
Object2;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;someword;789
Object3;123;Something;456;Something2;Keyword;789;Object4;123
Something;456;Something2;0;0
```

I've detected how many lines got those Keywords and the number of the row:

```
import csv
class FixIt:
 def test(self):
  count = 0
  with open('input.csv',mode='r') as file
   read = csv.reader(file)
   for num,row in enumerate(reader):
   count+=1
   if 'Keyword' in row[0]:
    print num, row
    count+=1
   print(count)
TryIt = FixIt()
TryIt.test()
```

I need to put x2 zeros or somestring values on the cells before the keyword to re-order the output to the original structure like:

```
col_1;col_2;col_3;col_4;col_5;col_6;col_7;col_8;col_9
Object1;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;someword;789
Object2;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;someword;789
Object3;123;Something;456;Something2;corrective_data;corrective_data;Keyword;789
Object4;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;someword;789
```

Maybe with pandas can be done but i don't know where or how to start, some orientation or answer will be kindly appreciated.

Try 1:

I've tryed to replace the string Keyword on each line by 0;0;Keyword with:

```
with open("input.csv", "r") as file_input:
 with open("output.csv", "w") as file_output:
  for line in file_input:
   file_output.write(line.replace('Keyword','0;0;Keyword'))
```

But the result is wrong, it adds a ";" inside every cell and puts the string ";"0;0;Keyword also. After seeing the file with vim i saw the fact that i'll need also to add a new row after the 789 (because i see a " " as breakline).

I'm so lost right now, maybe creating 1 object and a list of properties for every row will be better (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, because your data in second code cell is not correctly formatted. I assume you want to make following changes:

```
col_1;col_2;col_3;col_4;col_5;col_6;col_7;col_8;col_9
Object3;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;someword;789
Object4;123;Something;456;Something2;Keyword;231

# TO #

col_1;col_2;col_3;col_4;col_5;col_6;col_7;col_8;col_9
Object3;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;someword;789
Object3;123;Something;456;Something2;0;0;Keyword;231
```

---

So here is how you can make the changes with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# input data from csv file
data = pd.read_csv("input.csv", delimiter=';') 

# get the indices of rows with "Keyword" appearing in col_6
idxs = data.loc[data['col_6'] == "Keyword"].index 

# copy value in col_6 to col_8
data.set_value(idxs, 'col_8', data.iloc[idxs]['col_6']) 
# copy value in col_7 to col_9
data.set_value(idxs, 'col_9', data.iloc[idxs]['col_7']) 

data.set_value(idxs, 'col_6', 0) # fill col_6 with 0
data.set_value(idxs, 'col_7', 0) # fill col_7 with 0

# write result to a new file
data.to_csv("result.csv", sep=';')
```

Comment: Thanks, i've done it with Bash reformatting the whole csv with tr and sed but it's nice to know the python and pandas way ( i'm still learning, seems a cool programming languaje ). Worked fine.